# Regex flavors translation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I am wondering if there is a good tool that translates RegEx from .NET(C#) syntax to Javascript, including all escaping rules. I have a RegEx that works in .NET inside RegExValidator but doesn't work inside Javascript:

```
^\s*\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*$
```

Javascript doesn't like apostrophy inside RegEx when used like sample below, but .NET didn't have a problem with that.

```
 $('#<%= ContactEMail.ClientID %>').blur(function() {

            if ((^\s*\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*$)).test($(this).val())
            {
                $(this).next('span').show();
            }
            else 
            {
                 $(this).next('span').hide();

            }

        });
```

Comment: how are you using this regex in javascript? put code.

Comment: @jotapdiez The regex that was posted is being used in .NET, and he's asking how to convert the syntax into JavaScript regex.

Comment: I think it's to validate an email address.

Comment: @Marcel - yes, it's e-mail validator, I posted javascript code how I plan to use it.

Comment: Perhaps you should use [this one](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: @Victor When you're defining your regex in Javascript are you using a string or a literal? i.e. `var rx = '\s*\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*';` or `var rx = /\s*\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*/`   -   If you're using the string method (first one), you'll need to escape the apostrophe with a backslash `\'`

Comment: @musicinmyhead - no, I used it like above, which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var regexp = /^\s*\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*$/g;
if ($(this).val().match(regexp))
    $(this).next('span').show();
else
    $(this).next('span').hide();
```

Match info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Hope help

Comment: Oh please, don't refer to w3schools.com but to a more proper source like [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions); see [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com) why.

Comment: @MarcelK OMG!, I didn't know that. Never more use w3c

Comment: thanks for reply. looks like javascript has a problem with apostrophy here as well

Comment: Wow, this is the first time this remark convinced the answerer immediately, instead of causing a heavy debate with almost religious spirit. BTW, don't interchange **W3Schools** and **W3C** as they are totally unrelated.

Comment: @Victor the regexp works for me. Try http://jsfiddle.net/aCU5t/ changing the email address

Comment: The apostrophe should not cause a problem in a regex literal.  Try using it exactly the way @Marcel did in his answer.

Comment: @Alan - yeah guys it's working thanks so much, I was just confused by ASP.NET page designer which looks like treats apostrophy as a literal sign. I have about 10 more of those RegEx that I need to translate hope Javascript RegEx rules match those of .NET

Comment: So you're going to accept @Marcel's answer, right?   @jotapdiez, I know his regex is the same as yours, but Marcel also explained the error and provided drop-in replacement code.  And he didn't add a `/g` modifier; why did you do that?

Comment: @Alan - this reply also provided `match` method which I ended up using. I would accept both answers if I could.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using a JavaScript literal; use slashes to delimit one, instead of parentheses:

```
if (/^\s*\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*$/.test($(this).val()))
```